# Why does this CSS hover transition fail in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, css, css-transitions

I've posted a simple example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tkJgg/

I know FF needs to have initial values set for the transition properties. I think I have that though. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tkJgg/1/)

Comment: I see the problem now. It's not the function "ease" it's the delay of 0. FF wants something like "0s" in order to work. The other browsers I tested on didn't care. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `0` at the end :

```
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

or specify the s(seconds) after zero :

```
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
```

The syntax say :

```
 <single-transition> = [ none | <single-transition-property> ] || <time> || <single-transition-timing-function> || <time>
```

where `<time>` is defined here :

[time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/time)

*The  CSS data type denotes time dimensions expressed in seconds or milliseconds. They consists of a `<number>` immediately followed by the unit.*

and moreover :

"*While unitless zero is allowed for `<length>`, it's invalid for all other units.*"

Comment: Yeah - if other browsers allow unitless time values, they're buggy.

Comment: .. not really but if you don't follow the specifications you can have different behaviors

Comment: Well yeah - here's hoping they fix it by the time they drop the prefixes.

Comment: I completely agree with you, those prefixes are really bad.

Answer (score 0):

The hover transition doesn't fails in Mozilla but sometimes because of code errors or fail loading the browser disables this property. **To ignore this** problem you should define the browser in the CSS transition. The following is the example that which code should be used in defining different main browsers

```
#mydiv a:hover{
   -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;     /*For Mozilla Browser*/ 
   -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;  /*For Chrome and Safari*/
   -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;       /*For Opera Browser*/
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;         /*For Other Browser*/
}
```

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: It means that we need to define browsers in the `CSS` code. Like `-moz-` in mozilla, thus I had defined all the browser codes.