# Firefox: Background-Image Transition over Div Elements won't work

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions

Just watch this in Firefox and in Chrome.
    http://jsfiddle.net/TBwXm/

```
        div#back {
        background: url('http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-250x250-Rope.jpg');
        width: 250px; height: 250px;
           -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease 0;
          -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
          -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease 0;
          -o-transition: all 1.5s ease 0;
        transition: all 1.5s ease-out 0;
    }
    div#back:hover { 
background:url('http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-250x250-Floral.jpg'); }
```

I've tried several things, like [Why is my CSS3 Transition not working in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084268/why-is-my-css3-transition-not-working-in-firefox) or [Why does this CSS hover transition fail in FireFox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659285/why-does-this-css-hover-transition-fail-in-firefox)

The included demo of the last link works on FF, I copied the source code and tried it with my div, but nothing happens.

Does someone know what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate : Try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354742/css3-transition-of-background-image-for-firefox-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can achieve it with a trick [(found here in SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808764/transition-for-background-image-in-firefox).

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBwXm/6/)

If we cant do it directly, we are going to use a state between the start and the end of the animation. In this state, just play with opacity and z-index.

```
div#back {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px; height: 250px;
}

#back:before, #back:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

#back:before {
    background-image: url('http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-250x250-Rope.jpg');
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 2s ease;
}

#back:after {
    background-image: url('http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-250x250-Floral.jpg');
    z-index: -2;
}

#back:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
```